# Is there any kind of irrational number wich does not contain digit 9?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

At first we must prove that there is or is`t irrational numbers which does not contain digit 9!
if there are many kind of such numbers, then there is another question:
how to write down algebraic expression about set of such numbers?

Comment: 0.101001000100001000001...

Comment: One example of a *transcendental* number is the Liouville number $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-n!}$, which has only $0$ and $1$ digits.

Comment: It seems that this set has a set-theoretic description like Cantor set, something like $\mathbb R\setminus (\mathbb Q\cup \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty 10^{-n}(\mathbb Z+[0.9;1)) )$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are uncountably many such.  One way to see that is to take any irrational number in base $9$.  There are no $9$'s in its expansion.  Now read the expansion in base $10$.  As repeating or not is independent of the base, it will still have no $9$'s in its expansion.